# how to have VSCode render a pair of double dollar $$Latex_code$$ as a new line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

a pair of double dollar $$Latex_code$$ renders a new line in jupyter notebook but does not work in VSCode.

[image]

I am using VSCode1.40.0 with [Markdown+Math plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=goessner.mdmath), do I need another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For working with LaTex in VSCode, a much-recommended extension is :

[Visual Studio Code LaTeX Workshop Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop)